# Understanding this proof: intersection of acceptable languages are acceptable

Tags: turing-machines

I'm reading [this](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs374/sp2018/A/notes/models/07-undecidable.pdf) and the first part in Lemma 4 is confusing:

> Lemma 4. For all acceptable languages L and L′, the languages L ∪ L′ and L ∩ L′ are also acceptable.
>
> Proof: Let M and M′ be Turing machines that decide L and L′, respectively.

I don't follow how we prove the existence of $M$ and $M'$. We know these languages $L$ and $L'$ are acceptable (as stated) but are they really decidable? From what I understand acceptable language $L$ implies a Turing machine that accepts every string of $w \in L$; a decidable language $L_D$ implies a Turning machine that accepts every string of $w \in L_D$ and halts for every $w \in \Sigma^*$ (or in other words does not diverge for any $w$).

Comment: Indeed, at first it says that machines $M$ and $M'$ decide $L$ and $L'$, respectively, but reading further, the first paragraph does take into account the case where $M$ or $M'$ diverge. Maybe it's just a typo?

Comment: True if it was "accept" instead of "decide" then the rest makes sense. I wanted to make sure I'm not missing any basics here.

Comment: I think that the author means "accepts". The combined machine accepts $w$ iff $M$ accepts $w$ *and* $M'$ accepts $w$.